# Xamarin, Android: Why is my background not transparent, when the .png is...?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

so ive created a fragment for my app where a window pops up, and asks whether to take the picture from the camera or to get it from the gallery. Everthing, but the two buttons in the middle, are exactly 1 .png. This background png (that also includes the texts), has two transparancies. One in the white background (which is at about 25 percent) and one in the black background that takes about most of the screen. This opacity level was first set to 1%, now it is set to 0. The black basically doesnt even exist anymore. Yet it is almost fully black. You can see from the image i attach, that one is bearly able to see anything through. But why is that?  Where does this heavy alpha channel come from?

Thanks! 
[image]

Comment: Could you include your code? I'm having a similar problem with XLabs ImageButton.

Comment: I fixed my issue by adding a transparent BackgroundColor to my view control.